# Difference between "setdefaultlanguage" vs "setmainlanguage"

Tags: polyglossia

What is the difference between `\setdefaultlanguage` vs `\setmainlanguage`? I have seen either one and also both used with `polyglossia`. I am confused as to which one I should use in my document.

Comment: Have you read the polyglossia documentation (the section about both commands)?

Comment: I had not. I didn't know both were `polyglossia`-commands. It states: You can determine the default language by means of the command:
`\setdefaultlanguage[⟨options⟩]{lang}` (or equivalently `\setmainlanguage`).

Comment: Yes, it is. What is the correct procedure for closing? I don't have a 'close' option anywhere. Might be a privileges issue, though.

Comment: What flag did you set?

Comment: Since this question is on-topic and we don't have a duplicate, wouldn't it be better to provide an answer that can be found using google?

Comment: @TeXnician There are several questions here that could be closed for the same reason, but they aren’t and shouldn’t.

Comment: @TeXnician would you care to provide an answer, then, since you were the one that found (or at least knew) the solution. In the end, even though the answer is fairly simple, some other guy living in the future might wonder about the same thing and also not know where to look right away. I hope it's not below you :D

Comment: @TeXnician Reopened!

Comment: and also edited for conciseness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The manual states on page 4 that you can set the primary language using `\setdefaultlanguage` and that `\setmainlanguage` acts identically (is a synonym).

Comment: I'd also remark that, in my opinion, `\setmainlanguage` is semantically better. Also `babel` has `main=<language>` and `fontspec` has `\setmainfont`.