# Package polyglossia not working

Tags: polyglossia, linux, python

I am using a linux system. By mistake I issued a command -

```
sudo apt-get purge python
```

(I know I've committed a very big mistake :( but now I want everything back to normal.)

As soon as I issued this command my LaTeX (`texlive-full`) stopped working. I realized that I did not had any version of `texlive`. I issued this command -

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

I don't know why, but now package `polyglossia` is not working. eg.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
    abcd
\end{document}
```

This should have run normally, but I'm getting errors.

[This](https://pastebin.com/219RbG7H) is the log file. Linux users please help me out!

Comment: The MWE works for me, but the TeX live in Linux package sources is known to lag behind current development, indeed you have `TeX Live 2017/Debian`, while current would be TeX live 2019. I think `\setdefaultlanguage` is a more recent addition to `polyglossia`, try `\setmainlanguage` instead. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394958/35864

Comment: The current version of `polyglossia` has `\let\setmainlanguage=\setdefaultlanguage`, so I suspect that `\setmainlanguage` instead of `\setdefaultlanguage` in the MWE should give the expected results.

Comment: If you want a more up-to-date system than the two-year-old TeX live 2017 from the Debian repositories, you may want to consider installing a current vanilla TeX live directly from TUG: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864

Comment: @moewe Please see the log file. I've used `setmainlanguage` and still I got errors.

Comment: Check the contents of `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia.sty` Does the file look roughly like https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/blob/master/tex/polyglossia.sty?

Comment: I copied this file and pasted there, but still no change

Comment: Pasting the contents of that file could mean serious version incompatibilities. What did *your* `polyglossia.sty` look like before you pasted the linked file?

Comment: The editor is not allowing me to undo the action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97551/discussion-between-niranjan-and-moewe).